# Is it possible to connect to the same computer WITHOUT loopback?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, ip, loopback

I'm trying to measure the speed of the connection between my computer and my router.

I'm using [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) for this, but the problem is that entering my own local IP address bypasses the network and connects my computer to itself via loopback.

Is there any way to bypass/disable the loopback and force the computer to connect via the router?

Comment: Note that if you're trying to measure a half-duplex connection like Wi-Fi, such tricks would make it show _less than half_ the actual speed (due to the same data being transferred from computer to router, and back to the computer).

Comment: @grawity: Makes sense, thanks for the note. I'm guessing I could probably just correct for this by multiplying by the appropriate factor (~4?) to get an estimate?

Comment: If your router supports hairpin NAT you could use port forwarding. Port forward to your local machine and then use your public IP as a the destination.